# WPF: Реализация выбора стиля линии

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Привет. На работе дали задание - создать меню для выбора стиля линии. Весь проект использует WPF, в котором я не очень силен.

Имеется линия, при ее выделении загружается менюшка, на которой я создал комбобокс. Вот код менюшки:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SchemeEditor.LinkingEditor.Editors.LineStyleEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbLineStyle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="cmbLineStyle_SelectionChanged" Loaded="cmbLineStyle_Loaded">
         <Line Fill="Black" X1="0" X2="470" Y1="5" Y2="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1,0" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="10,2,10,2"/>
         <Line Fill="Black" X1="0" X2="470" Y1="5" Y2="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1,1" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="10,2,10,2"/>
         <Line Fill="Black" X1="0" X2="470" Y1="5" Y2="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2,1,1,1" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="10,2,10,2"/>
         <Line Fill="Black" X1="0" X2="470" Y1="5" Y2="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2,2" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="10,2,10,2"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Насколько я понимаю, за стиль линии отвечает свойство `StrokeDashArray`, имеющее тип `DoubleCollection`.

Собственно, реализовать почти получилось за исключением одной мелкой, но важной детали: мне нужно, чтобы при выборе линии комбобокс выводил стиль выбранной линии. Я могу получить свойство `StrokeDashArray`, но в голову уже несколько дней не лезет ни одной мысли, как бы вывести его в комбобокс.

Начал с очень костыльного варианта: продублировать все стили в `Dictionary`, где ключ - это `DoubleCollection`, а значение - `Int` (index). Дальше я перебираю все ключи, сравниваю их с выбранным стилем и если есть совпадение, то получаю из словаря индекс и свойство комбобокса `SelectedIndex` меняю на полученный. По идее это должно работать, если бы не одно НО. `DoubleCollection` очень плохо сравниваются друг с другом и получается, что я имею два значения {1,0} и {1,0}, которые должны быть равны, но все равно вылезает ошибка, что такого ключа в словаре нет.

Вот код обработчика события загрузки менюшки:

```
private void cmbLineStyle_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleCollection dashArray = editingValue.ConstValue;

    int index = linesList[dashArray];
    cmbLineStyle.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Я понимаю, что это жуткий костыль, но в голову другие решения не лезут. Помогите, пожалуйста! Никак не могу побороть столь легкое задание.

Comment: Важный вопрос: а что такое в вашем случае _стиль линии_? Это важно. Если не знаете сходу — спросите у вашего архитектора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не, вы делаете как-то не по-WPF-овски.

Разделите вашу логику на VM и View.

Для начала VM. Я не знаю, какой тип у вас будет означать стиль линии, обозначим его покамест как `S`.

Вам нужно по идее следующее:

```
static public class Styles
{
    public static ReadOnlyList<S> All { get; } = ...; // тут все стили
}
```

Далее, текущий стиль должен быть доступен как свойство в вашей VM, пусть соответствующее свойство называется `CurrentStyle`.

Окей, дальше XAML. Делаете как-то так: Список всех стилей привязываете через `ItemsSource`, текущий выбранный стиль — через `SelectedItem`. Вам ещё нужен `ItemTemplate`, который будет описывать, как выглядит линия данного стиля.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:Styles.All}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentStyle}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Height="15" Name="Outer">
                <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Outer}"
                      Y1="8" Y2="8"
                      Stroke="Black"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

В `DataTemplate`'е вам нужно описать, как выглядит линия данного стиля. Нужные свойства будут доступны через `Binding`. Например, если это просто `StrokeDashArray`, то ваш `CurrentStyle` должен быть типа `DashArray` или классом, содержащим свойство типа `DashArray`. Привязавшись к нему:

```
                <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Outer}"
                      Y1="8" Y2="8"
                      Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="{Binding}"/>
```

получаем вот такую картинку:

[image: линии с точечками]

Comment: О, класс, спасибо! Как раз с привязками не знал толком что делать.

Comment: @MartyFoxy: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Я бы рекомендовал вам изучить механизм привязки данных (Data Binding) и реализовать всё в его помощью.

http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level8/8_6.php